Creating many text boxes in PySide6 Qt without slowing things down
I am very new to Qt/PySide6 and am trying to create an app that edits text in many little boxes. To give some idea of how many boxes, I think it should easily be able to handle 10,000 boxes.
Here's what I tried initially:
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QPlainTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QScrollArea,
)

DATA = ["hello\n\n"]*10000

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textArray = []
        for v in DATA:
            self.textArray.append(QPlainTextEdit(v))

        for text in self.textArray:
            layout.addWidget(text)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(widget)


        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()


Unfortunately, this is way too slow (it takes maybe 30 seconds for the app window to show up when I run it and my laptop fan starts spinning...).
But now consider the following:
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QPlainTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QScrollArea,
)

DATA = ["hello\n\n"]*10000

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textfield = QPlainTextEdit("".join(v for v in DATA))

        layout.addWidget(self.textfield)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(widget)


        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()

This is the same amount of data, but it's just all stored in a single QPlainTextEdit widget, and it runs very fast. So this makes me wonder whether it is possible to somehow create (for the user) an illusion that there are 10,000 separate boxes, even though on the Qt/internal level there's just a single QPlainTextEdit (or some other) widget tracking the state. However, I don't know enough about Qt to know whether such a thing is possible and how to go about doing it if it is. Alternatively, maybe there is some other approach that would work better.
I am fine with each box not having its own edit history/undo sequence, but there should be some way to programmatically "know" the contents of each box separately, to know which box is currently being edited, and operations like Ctrl-a to select all text should only select the text inside the current box.

QPlainTextEdit is a widget. Specifically, it inherits from: QAbstractScrollArea, QFrame, QWidget, and QObject (and, actually, the Python object used to wrap the C++ instance). It also contains some inner objects, such as a QTextDocument and some other private Qt objects that provide drawing and interaction capabilities for its text contents. Simply put, consider the difference between writing a novel containing 10k letters in a notebook, or writing every single letter of that novel on a paper sheet, putting each sheet in an envelope, and putting that envelope in a box.

Now, it's quite pointless to show so many letters/characters vertically put on a scroll area (scrolling would be completely unreliable), which makes the purpose of your question ambiguous; I'm assuming you're trying to create some sort of binary/character viewer, so you probably want to use a custom item view. A QTableView (or even a QTableWidget) may suffice, as 10k characters are fundamentally a 100x100 grid, and possibly with a custom delegate. I strongly suggest you to start by patiently studying the model/view programming guide.

@musicamante Thank you for the response! I am not trying to build a binary/character viewer. I'm trying to build a text editor of sorts, but I want both the editor and user to be aware that the file consists of various "notes". I could just have a single editing area and then use some sort of markup language, but I would prefer to be able to write anything at all in a box, hence wanting separate boxes at the UI level. Would your suggested link still be suitable for this case?

@IssaRice Your current UI design seems utterly unworkable from a user POV. There's no value whatsoever in listing tens of thousands of notes at the same time, since only a small number can ever fit on the screen. Most applications of this general type (e.g. database viewers), employ paging to enable efficient scrolling through large numbers of records. There are many different ways to implement this: the most appropriate approach depends on the exact nature of the data being modelled. Your question is currently far too vague to provide specific advice.

@IssaRice Your description is vague. Do you need a text editor that features widgets ("notes") that can add some further text/data anchored to a certain portion of text? Or do you want some "floating" notes, like a virtual desktop with post-it like widgets? Or is it just some form of task list (similarly to Google tasks)? Each of these may require quite different approaches, but, as ekhumoro noted above, showing everything at once is certainly not appropriate, and any of the cases above would probably deal with simple viewers that only display the content and eventually become editable.

@ekhumoro I currently use Emacs to accomplish the same thing I'm trying to do with this new Qt app that I am trying to create. I have a single text file with thousands of separate "notes" (separated by lines containing only "====="). So I disagree that the UI design is utterly unworkable (because I am already using a similar UI and I like it). The value in listing all notes at once is that I can easily search or scroll across the whole buffer without having to load more notes into memory (because everything is already loaded from the start).

I did not want to come across as self-promotional, so I initially withheld the exact details of what I was trying to create, but since more details might be helpful for people to help me, here is the thing I am trying to recreate in Qt: https://github.com/riceissa/spaced-inbox Basically, if I just use Emacs it's kind of hard to track the identities of the individual notes, so I'd like the concept of a "note" to be reified in the UI. But I still want everything else to work as in Emacs (e.g. showing all notes at once).

@musicamante Out of the ones you listed, the closest one is a task list. But see the link in my previous comment for more details -- it's more of a diary or a research journal. Showing everything at once is quite important to me, to give the feeling that they are just editing a single text file.

@IssaRice From what you describe, a possible option might be a QListView, with a custom QAbstractListModel that contains a "note entry" for each of its indexes. Then, create a custom delegate, override createEditor() and return a QPlainTextEdit instead of the default (which is a QLineEdit).

@IssaRice You misunderstand. What is unworkable is creating tens of thousands of separate widgets (whether directly editable or not). This isn't the same thing as editing a single file (with embedded separators) in a single editor. Efficient searching doesn't require showing all the notes either, since the backing model can be queried independently without rendering any of its data in a viewer. There's an important difference between showing vs loading everything at once. The former is needlessly inefficient, since the user only ever sees a tiny subset at any given moment.

I recommend this.
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QPlainTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QScrollArea,
)

DATA = ["hello\n\n"]*10000

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textfield = QPlainTextEdit()
        
        tc = self.textfield.textCursor()
        tc.beginEditBlock()
        for  data in DATA:
            tc.insertText(data)
        tc.endEditBlock()
        layout.addWidget(self.textfield)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(widget)


        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()

The reason why your code costs too long time:
qplaintextedit and qtextedit , both have a qtextdocument to edit.
The qtextdocument has its own documentLayout.
There is documentChanged function in the layout class.
Every you edit the qtextdocument, this function is called.
This function relayouts all document every time.
For example, 1: "hello" # relayout for this block...
2: "hello" # relayout for this block and the previous blocks...
3: "hello" # relayout for this block and the previous blocks...
The cost of execution takes 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7.....10000
50005000　calles.
But beginEditBlock and endEditBlock sums the callings to only once.
